# Visual Studio 2012 SDT - Tabular Model Designer Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssas, ssas-tabular, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to create a Tabular Model using Visual Studio 2012 Server Data Tools. I made my install using Multidimensional Schema because I've some reports that are reading data from cubes.

But I want to try the Tabular Model but without disconnect my cubes...

When I start the Tabular I receive the following message:

```
"The workspace database localhost is not running tabular mode"
```

I already read some "solutions" but I'm not getting how can I solve this problem.

Here is the screen with the error:

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to continue developing other Multidimensional SSAS models and deploying them to the existing SSAS instance then you can always run the SQL install media and install a new instance of SSAS, this time in Tabular model.

Or if you don't need the existing SSAS Multidimensional instance you can change it to Tabular following these [instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130525153920/https://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/) by Cathy Dumas.

Comment: many thanks! I install a new instance in Tabular Mode... How can I say to SSAS that I want to use that new instance?

Comment: @John_Rodgers if you close and open Visual Studio and open the project does it prompt you again for the workspace database?